# Sort every thirdparty imports as different sections using isort

Tags: python, isort

I'm trying to work with **flake8** and **isort** libraries. I want to sort every third-party module into different sections, in easy words I want a new line between every third-party module. For example I have this

```
import flask
from connexion import ProblemException
from connexion.decorators.validation import RequestBodyValidator
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionRequest, ConnexionResponse
```

and I want this to be

```
import flask

from connexion import ProblemException
from connexion.decorators.validation import RequestBodyValidator
from connexion.lifecycle import ConnexionRequest, ConnexionResponse
```

EDIT: My current `pyproject.toml` file setting

```
[tool.isort]
force_sort_within_sections = false
lines_between_sections = 1
order_by_type = false
case_sensitive = true
```

Comment: flake8 doesn't format code so i've removed it -- what have you tried so far? the isort documentation is pretty straightforward on how to accomplish what you're doing

Comment: @AnthonySottile Looking at the [manual](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/custom_sections_and_ordering.html) I see how to add sections for known modules, but OP wants a blank line between each different library's import, in general and presumably without having to know ahead of time the list of all libraries.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, it looks like the `group_by_package` option would do the trick. See https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html

Comment: @joanis thanks for the comment, but unfortunately this is not working with my current setting. I have added the current setting.

Comment: @testtest What happens when you add `group_by_package` to your config?

Comment: Hum, it doesn't work for me either, the option just seems to be ignored. Submit a bug report to isort?

Comment: @joanis yes. it does not work. I'll submit a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `group_by_package` option:
(in `.isort.cfg`)

```ini
[settings]
group_by_package=True
```

(in `pyproject.toml`)

```ini
[tool.isort]
group_by_package=True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but unfortunately, this is not working with my current setting. I have added the current setting.

Comment: @pigrammer What version of isort are you using? Did this actually work for your project? I just tested adding this option to my isort config and it has no effect. If you tested it and it works for you, I'd like to know what your config is so I can compare with mine and with OP's.